# How to convert Html to PostScript using GhostScript?

Tags: html, pdf, ghostscript, postscript

I want to convert html to PDF in order to converting it i found that direct conversion is not possible so i choose a method html-->PS-->PDF i have successfully convert PS to PDF but cant convert html to PS through ghost script  now can anyone please tell me is it actually possible or not and if it is then how ?

Platform - Windows 
note - No thirt pary/paid/dll tools plesae

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ghostscript does not interpret HTML, so no you cannot take HTML and create a PostScript (or PDF) file using Ghostscript directly. Since you can't convert HTML to PDF using Ghostscript, why would you think you could convert HTML to PostScript with it ?

You can (in general) print from a browser window to a virtual PostScript printer in order to create PostScript.

If that isn't acceptable then you will need to use some other means to create PostScript from HTML, in which case you may as well just go straight to PDF. wkhtmltopdf is open source, you could try that.

Comment: very very thanks to your answer can i use wkhtml to pdf for commercial purpose ?

Comment: As you can see from the website, its LGPL licenced.

Comment: @Praveen_Kumar  I am facing a similar issue where I need to convert html to pdf. Can you please tell me how you made it work ?